# Android Chatting application

Tags: android, livechat

I am making a chatting application in android. I am able to perform the live chatting. But i am not able to get when the user is online or offline. How can I achieve the same

Thanks

here is the code

```
private void getListener() {
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry rosterEntry : entries) {
            String user = rosterEntry.getUser();
            Presence presence = roster.getPresence(user);
            System.out.println("User : " + user);
            System.out.println("Presence : " + presence); // 1
            System.out.println("Presence type: " + presence.getType()); // 2
            System.out.println("Presence mode: " + presence.getMode());
        }
    }
```

but i always get the status unavailable, also when the person is available.
Please tell me any solution what to do??
Thanks

Comment: How can anyone answer your question without knowing a thing about your implementation?

Comment: Post code of the class, question is very vague.

Comment: sory trickster. I am posting code rite now.

Comment: @Trickster please help me now. I have posted the code

Comment: @Trickster where are you now???

Comment: Is your project confidential one? Because, there is no line of code where you are setting the status of the user. Also, there are other users in the app as well, so you need to sync the status to server as well. There must be lot of code which I needed before I can through my answer.

Comment: yar actually i have user asmack library and nothing else, and i have not written any code further for showing online and ofline. I just want to first print the status then i'l do further. Can u tell me how sync can be done. Server is showing the online and ofline status but i am always getting UNAVAILABLE in S.O.P
Please help me @Trickster

Answer (score 0):

Add an **Online** field to your users db, once logged it changed to **true**, once logged off changed it to **false**. In your chatting app, regularly (every 180 seconds) request your server for the user's Online field, and show that to the users.

Comment: Please reply me???? the code didnt worked for me. I have updated my code,, please suggest any solution

Comment: Do you set the flag on once the user logs in? and off when the user logs  off?

Comment: No I have not made any provision like this.. as it is done on run time basis

Comment: I don't know what exactly your Presence or Roster class do, but I told the general procedure for doing such a task

Comment: Thanks bro. but my case is not so simple, Thanks